# How to know which action has been chosen in a receiver of an IntentServer?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to know which of the actions I offer in an Intent is the one the user selects:

So far I've tried the following code:

On my main activity:

```
Intent receiver = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FileChoosingReceiver.class)
                                    .putExtra("test", "test");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(intent, "Seleccione modo", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, file_req_code);
```

On my manifest, I've the defined the receiver as the following:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.webviewforgeoserver.FileChoosingReceiver" >
        </receiver>
```

And finally the class FileChoosingReceiver is set as:

```
public class FileChoosingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {



    }

}
```

onReceive is called when one of the actions is called but… I see no option that either in context or intent parameter, that would allow me to differentiate one from the other.

What am I missing that could give me which of the available options is the one chosen?

Comment: I would have expected the `data` facet, an extra, or something else in the `Intent` to identify the chosen item. If you examine that `Intent` in a debugger or dump it to Logcat, do you see anything?

Comment: @CommonsWare, no, I opened both parameters in debugger and gave a good look to all their fields, but I didn't see even one that seemed to be related to which option had been chosen.